# Should i test static local files in JS?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I have static local JSON files, that contains a lot of data, like countries, states, maps data.

```
{
  "CN": {
    "value": "CN",
    "label": "China"
  },
  "TW": {
    "value": "TW",
    "label": "Taiwan, China"
  },
  "HK": {
    "value": "HK",
    "label": "Hong Kong"
  },
}
```

Should i write a unit tests to check if have object length of X, and check others properties, labels/values, or this considered as a waste of time and not needed code?

like what i did is the following:

```
describe('country', () => {
  describe('Check object structure', () => {
    it('Should return US for US object', () => {
      expect(englishCountries.US.value).to.eql('US');
    });

    it('Should return CN for CN object', () => {
      expect(chineseCountries.CN.value).to.eql('CN');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Not really.. I'd check with one object and be done with it. But if for whatever reason you want to test for each object, I'd put the keys in an array and write my expect within the loop, instead of creating a separate block for each of them that essentially have the same structure.

Comment: Either in arrays or object, my point here, adding these cases would make the system more covered? or there's no value from adding them?

Comment: The point of unit testing is to test the functions.. Testing for data is not the objective of unit testing.. So from the point of view of unit testing, this adds no value... However, if you have a function that accesses this object, then it makes sense to test write unit tests around that function, not data...

Comment: I'd agree with Aditya. Usually having a static file means it would be input to some file. If this file is changed, automatically the logic in second file will be tested and would be highlighted. Purpose of testing is to cover all scenarios possible and not checking static hardcoded files

Comment: Got it, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should ! Not to see the success results but for checking so that you yourself have a hands on experience about new things.

Comment: Well, it's not about getting my hands dirty with that, but i mean adding these cases would enrich me in making the system more covered?